# How to Link Lib.a in IOS, static as well as dynamic linking?

Tags: ios, flutter, zeromq, ffi, dart-ffi

## I have some open source c++ library , I have converted into lib.a for different IOS architecture, how can I  link this library in Xcode For IOS Devices.

### http://wiki.zeromq.org/build:iphone

Reference Link

The Main Target is to first test this in IOS environment and then add it to Flutter, using Flutter FFi package, If anyone have done such  kind of work please guide.

Comment: When you get to doing this in Flutter, it's often easiest to have the Flutter toolchain compile the source - see https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/android/c-interop#open-source-third-party

Comment: For Reference https://pub.dev/packages/dartzmq This Library has Android Support ,But  does not Work On IOs,  I have Tried Many things but nothing Worked for me

Comment: Yes I have Read the Documentation, but did'nt  understood for IOS,  For Android It is Simple , we have .so  lib files, but for ios It is confusing me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my Solution,if using cocoa pods for managing dependencies I had to add these lines
  `s.vendored_libraries = 'Frameworks/lib.a' s.pod_target_xcconfig = { "OTHER_LDFLAGS" => "-force_load $(PODS_TARGET_SRCROOT)/Frameworks/lib.a -lstdc++" }`

other way to is to in Build Setting of Xcode  go to tab Link libraries with binary  and chose the lib.a file, add compiler linker flag in other flag section, compiler flags should be same with which to you build the library,
add necessary header search path,